# Add additional non-rewrite .htaccess directives on multisites via mod_rewrite_rules filter

Tags: multisite, htaccess, mod-rewrite

According to the example on [Adding your own .htaccess contents via WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3AAmereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly) it's possible to extend the .htaccess file via theme/plugin. for example:

```
<?php
function my_htaccess_contents( $rules )
{
$my_content = <<<EOD
\n # BEGIN My Added Content
# Protect wpconfig.php
<Files wp-config.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
# END My Added Content\n
EOD;
    return $my_content . $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
```

will result into the following .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN My Added Content
# Protect wpconfig.php
<Files wp-config.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
# END My Added Content

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work for multisites.

Any suggestion how to do handle this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do it. The .htaccess is "printed in the screen" of the wp-admin ones you are setting up the multisite (the same for wp-config.php). That info is never write directly in .htaccess file like the single site.

The wordpress core code for multisite / htaccess is here:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/703d5bdc8deb17781e9c6d8f0dd7e2c6b6353885/wp-admin/includes/network.php#L543

Comment: +1 but it is misleading, should probably be "there is no built-in way to do it" ;)

Comment: Yes, my English is not the best :)